# Formatting of single precision IEEE 754 floating point numbers

Tags: formatting, floating-point

I need to represent single precision numbers as text in a way that won't lose any information (so I can get the same number back, possibly disregarding NaNs etc.), but without too many spurious digits - so single precision 0.1 comes out as "0.1" not "0.100000001490116".

I'm not trying to save bytes, these extra digits are just confusing.

Is there a simple way to do that? I can see at least 8 significant decimal digits will be needed to represent 23+1 bits (12345678.0 and 12345679.0 are different in single precision), and that it would be enough with binary exponent (`12345b-11` sort of notation) but is this guaranteed to be enough decimal exponent notation (`1.2345e+6`) or one that uses 0-padding (`0.0000123456` - usually more readable, and these zeroes don't bother me much)?

Any `printf` formats, or exact instructions much appreciated.

Comment: Are you aware that 0.1 cannot be represented exactly with (binary) floating-point numbers? If you create a float from 0.1, you *can't* get 0.1 out again, unless you round.

Comment: Or are you considering an *alternative* to using an inbuilt floating-point type? If all you're trying to do is represent decimal numbers exactly (within a given range), consider the decimal floating-point types available in your language of choice.

Comment: You totally misunderstood the question - it is about representing single precision IEEE 754 floating point numbers as textual decimals, NOT the other way around you misread it to be. `"0.1"` is a perfectly valid representation for floating point number normally encoded as `3D CC CC CD`, as would be `"1.0e-1"`, `"0.100000002"`, `"0.09999999842"`, and many other formatted strings. Floating point number normally encoded as `3D CC CC CD` mathematically equals exactly 0.100000001490116119384765625 (0xCCCCCD * 2**-27), but that would be very inconvenient notation.

Comment: You're looking for a roundtrip representation, right? My recommendation stands (use decimal floating-point rather than binary), though I understand it might not be feasible in your case. Otherwise, you have an essentially impossible task - how will you know if your representation is "correct"? Or are you retaining the original decimal representation of the number?

Comment: Again, I am not. Data is already there, it's single precision floats, and that's it. Everything else is user interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing this right is a very non-trivial task: the problem is the subject of multiple academic papers.

Many open source projects use David M. Gay's [dtoa.c](http://www.netlib.org/fp/dtoa.c) library for this. If you use Python, dtoa.c-based rounding was recently (2.7/3) released, and the discussion on the relevant task discussion is very worthwhile:

- [Issue 1580: Use shorter float repr when possible](http://bugs.python.org/issue1580)

If you want to know (lots) more:

- Mike Cowlishaw's [Bibliography on Decimal Arithmetic: Conversions](http://speleotrove.com/decimal/decbibconversion.html)
- David M. Gay's paper describing dtoa.c, [*Correctly Rounded Binary-Decimal and Decimal-Binary Conversions*](http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/doc/90/4-10.ps.gz)

Comment: Ouch, this looks a lot messier than I expected. Fortunately I don't need perfect representation every time, so I'll just try low-precision conversion with `"%g"`, and if it doesn't convert back to correct answer I'll fall back to standard library code with all spurious digits.